# IE9 jquery Load function problem

Tags: jquery

This is the full code what i am looking for.

First black screen will come, after that logo loads with fadein affect. after 2sec the full div will be faded out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
     $('#splash-logo').hide()
        .load(function () {
             $('#splash-logo').fadeIn(2000, function() {
                   $('#splash').fadeOut(1000);  
              });
        });
});
</script>


<style type="text/css">
#splash{
    background:#000;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:98px;
}
body{
    margin:0;
}
</style>


<div id="splash">
<img src="" id="#splash-logo" />
</div>
```

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? Please be specific.

Comment: Please define *not working*. And to do this the best way is to first define what is the expected result (i.e. what are you trying to achieve), what have you tried (you've already showed this), the actual result you are getting and how it differs from the expected result. For example if you get some error message you will probably want to post this error message.

Comment: Do you have the latest version?  I think there was a bug with Load in 1.5 with IE9

Comment: i am sorry guys there is some problem with code i am not able to copy paste what i am looking for... is there any suggestion to paste my code in this topic... let me know

Answer (score 1):

The elements you're working with haven't been loaded when `window` is loaded. They only become available once the DOM has fully loaded.

As such, change your initial `load` method to be applied to the `document` object, rather than the `window` object:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#splash-logo').hide()
        .load(function () {
            $('#splash-logo').fadeIn(2000, function() {
                $('#splash').fadeOut(1000);  
            });
        });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `window` to `document`

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
 $('#splash-logo').hide()
    .load(function () {
         $('#splash-logo').fadeIn(2000, function() {
                $('#splash').fadeOut(1000);  
            });
        });
});
```

If you want to use `window`, you have to use the JQuery `load` function instead of `ready`

```
$(window).load(function () {
  // run code
});
```